# Generically pass different parameters to the method

Tags: java, generics, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

Lets assume I've two variables ;

```
Future<MyCustomObj1> mytask1 = <something 1>
Future<MyCustomObj2> mytask2 = <something 2 >
```

I want to cancel both tasks in case of any InterruptException,

so something like

```
mytask1.cancel(true);
mytask2.cancel(true);
```

instead of repeating it everywhere, I want to create a generic method which can take the Future task as argument and just call cancel.

```
public void cancelTasks(<fill here>) {
   <fill here>.cancel(true);
}
```

What should I substitute for `<fill here>` ?

Comment: you can use `Future` or `Future<?>`

Comment: exactly what i was looking for. Thanks. I missed this, where can i read more about these ?

Comment: any book about object oriented programming first and then any book about java generics

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html

Comment: now, when we solved your first question - have you avoided repeating lines?

Comment: @Lashane : Yes, i did.

Comment: how exactly? replacing of `mytask1.cancel(true);` with `cancelTasks(mytask1);` does not change anything actually

Comment: Why not ? cancelTasks(Future<?> mytask){} will not work ?

Comment: it will, but my question - how have you avoided repeating lines? probably you need to fully implement your idea and then return back here

Answer (score 1):

`Future<?> future`

It means "a `Future` of some unknown type".